# Integers and recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, scope, integer

The code below is to generate balanced Parenthesis

```
class Solution:
        def generateParenthesis(self, n: int) -> List[str]:
            res = []
            self.backtrack(n, res, 0, 0, [])
            return res

        def backtrack(self, n, res, o, c, path):

            print(o, c, path)
            if len(path) == 2*n:
                res.append("".join(path))
                return 
            if o < n:
                o += 1
                self.backtrack(n, res, o, c, path + ['('])

            if c < o:
                c += 1
                self.backtrack(n, res, o, c, path + [')'])
```

The output for the prints when n = 3 is,

```
0 0 []
1 0 ['(']
2 0 ['(', '(']
3 0 ['(', '(', '(']
3 1 ['(', '(', '(', ')']
3 2 ['(', '(', '(', ')', ')']
3 3 ['(', '(', '(', ')', ')', ')']
3 1 ['(', '(', ')']
3 2 ['(', '(', ')', ')']
3 3 ['(', '(', ')', ')', ')']
2 1 ['(', ')']
3 1 ['(', ')', '(']
3 2 ['(', ')', '(', ')']
3 3 ['(', ')', '(', ')', ')']
3 2 ['(', ')', ')']
3 3 ['(', ')', ')', ')']
1 1 [')']
2 1 [')', '(']
3 1 [')', '(', '(']
3 2 [')', '(', '(', ')']
3 3 [')', '(', '(', ')', ')']
3 2 [')', '(', ')']
3 3 [')', '(', ')', ')']
2 2 [')', ')']
3 2 [')', ')', '(']
3 3 [')', ')', '(', ')']
3 3 [')', ')', ')']
```

I get what is happening up to 3-3 ( first one ) but after that why is 3-1 only got 2 open brackets but with o equal to 3, at first I assumed its because the variable o has been set out of the scope from previous recursion to always be 3, but then later o is seen to be equal to 2 so thats not it.

I am aware of this behaviour in data structures like lists and sets which is why I add items inside the function call to avoid them being changed for every recrusive call but is the same behviour true for integers as well ? Which would explain why it works when I do the o + 1 inside the function call instead.

Could someone please give a refresher on this !

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just for the reference, here is my approach for this problem. You could compare with yours.

```
class Solution(object):
    def generateParenthesis(self, n):
        
        def paren(left, right, curr, res):
            # evalue current string
            # if out of brackets to add, it must be a valid one
            if left == 0 and right == 0:
                res.append(curr)
                return

            # recursive call: add either open or close
            if left > 0:
                # add open bracket, decr count
                paren(left-1, right, curr + "(", res)

            # if adding close bracket is valid
            if right > left:
                # add close bracket, decr count
                paren(left, right-1, curr + ")", res)

            return res
        # end paren()

        res = paren(n, n, '', [])

        return res
```

Comment: I was trying to understand why we have to put the left-1/right-1 inside the function call instead of outside it. Like what is the difference in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You should call backtrack with `o+1` as its parameter instead of modifying `o` within the function because it skews your next condition that uses `o` (and causes a discrepancy with the content of path).

There are only 3 ways you can add more parentheses to an existing pattern of matched parentheses.  So the recursion is very simple.  You just need to eliminate duplicate patterns.  Here's a generator that does it:

```
def parent(N, pattern="",seen=None):
    if seen is None: seen = set()
    if N:
        yield from parent(N-1,f"{pattern}()",seen)
        yield from parent(N-1,f"({pattern})",seen)
        yield from parent(N-1,f"(){pattern}",seen)
    elif pattern not in seen:
        seen.add(pattern)
        yield pattern
```

output

```
print(*parent(3))

# ()()() (()()) (())() ((())) ()(())
```

You could also use the well known Left-Right algorithm that balances the parentheses using two counters that must both be zero for the pattern to be complete.

It adds a left parenthesis to the current pattern when there are left parentheses available (left side) and recurses to get them closed.

A right closing parenthesis is added when there are pending (unclosed) left parentheses and the recursion continues to open or close more with the remaining parentheses. This does not generate duplicates because opening and closing only occurs on distinct levels of imbalance.

```
def paren(L,R=None,pattern=''):
    if R is None: R = L
    if not L and not R: yield pattern;return
    if L>0: yield from paren(L-1,R,pattern+"(")
    if R>L: yield from paren(L,R-1,pattern+")")
```

Comment: I am asking what the way I add counters ( outside the function call ) is doing

Comment: Added the explanation at the beginning of my answer